# How to access XML value in Node-RED

Tags: xml, web-services, node-red

I have a web service response in XML. I want to extract the 'available' tag value in node-red. I have placed the XML node before a function node and I tried accessing the value as `msg.payload.agentAvailability.available` in my function. It ends while reporting an error undefined.

[image]

This is how my node-red flow looks like. 
[image]

Any help will be appearciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed out the `$` key in your path.

Try the following:

```
msg.payload.agentAvailability["$"].available
```

Comment: You are right. It worked after adding $ in the path. Thanks for the quick reply.